# HTTP::Headers with say

Tags: perl

Here is a simple script for a Net::Server::HTTP

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use v5.12;

use HTTP::Headers;

use base qw(Net::Server::HTTP);
__PACKAGE__->run(port => 'localhost:8421');

sub process_http_request
{
  my ($self) = @_;
  my $header = HTTP::Headers->new();

  $header->content_type('text/html');

  print $header->as_string() . "\n"; # <- this works
  # say $header->as_string() . "\n"; # <- this doesn't work and I still have to add a newline

  say "<!doctype html>";
  say "<html>";
  say "<head>";
  say "  <title>Test</title>";
  say "</head>";
  say "<body>";
  say "<h1>Test</h1>";
  say "</body>";
  say "</html>";
}
```

I assumed that by using `say` I could get round adding a newline, but I have to add it and it breaks the `HTTP::Header`, by adding another newline to each HTTP field, which doesn't make sense as `as_string` is suggest it's a string. Can someone please explain what is actually going on here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The bug seems to be that the software does not properly delegate to [Net::Server::TiedHandle](http://kobesearch.cpan.org/htdocs/Net-Server/Net/Server.pm.html#package-Net%3a%3aServer%3a%3aTiedHandle-)'s SAY method, only to PRINT. I do not know how to repair this.

I suggest you use [Plack](http://p3rl.org/Plack) for your Web applications instead.

file `app.psgi`:

```
my $html = <<'HTML';
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Test</h1>
</body>
</html>
HTML

my $app = sub {
    return [200, [Content_Type => 'text/html'], [$html]];
};
```

command-line:

```
plackup --port 8421
```